# Is it possible to detect if an <img>-tag is positioned at the correct spot in an html document?

Tags: c#, html, tags, vs-unit-testing-framework

I would like to know if it is possible to detect if an `<img>`-tag is positioned correctly in an HTML document. I did some research but I only got information on how to position it on the actual displayed site. What I'm looking for is the position inside the code of an HTML document (in the source code). I would like to test in C# Unit Tests whether a certain `<img>`-tag is positioned correctly.

Edit: The `<img>`-tag has no special identifier (yet) so I'll have to implement that in before, if it is even possible to detect a tags position based off the id.

Edit 2: This is what a the HTML document generally looks like:

```
<div>
    <p class="MsoNormal"><span style='color:#1F497D;mso-fareast-language:DE'>disclaimer should be here<o:p></o:p></span></p>
</div>
<p class="MsoNormal"><span style='color:#1F497D'><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></p>
<div>
    <div>
        <p>
            <span style="font-family: Calibri;">
                <span style="font-size: 8.5pt; font-family: Calibri;"><br>
                </span>
            </span>
        </p>
        <p>
            <span style="font-family: Calibri;">
                <span style="font-size: 11px;"><img src="cid:__Image_00000020" alt="" title="" width="499pxpx">
                </span>
            </span>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

If that is possible, I'd love to know what can be used to test this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: im not asking for where it is positioned in the browser but in the source code

Comment: i dont need to find out whether anything is left or right. i just want to track down a tags position as you can see in the code i posted. All I want is to check whether the image is added where you can read the string "disclaimer should be here"

Comment: You can work with you `HTML` as with `XML` (or with help of some 3rd-party library like [HAP](https://html-agility-pack.net/)) and check if there is a node on a specific `XPath`

Comment: it looks promising after taking a quick look at it. I'll dig deeper

Comment: so after using `HAP` for a few days now I wrote some code that returns me the path to the requested `disclaimer tag`. The only way on how to check if its positioned correctly in the html source code is by creating templates and checking if the returned path matches any of the templates `<img>` paths, right? @vasily.sib

Comment: I was originally talking about creating some `XPath` like: `//div[@class='MsoNormal']//img` and this checking `if (document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(xPath).Count == 0) { /* no <img> on expected XPath */ }`

Comment: oh, I forgot to mention that i work with emails, sry on that one. Basically what I did is going grabbing the emails attachments and the contentIds which allowed me to create the following xpath: `//img[@src="cid:" + contentId]`. Using some conditions i checked for availability and then I used recursion to loop through every parentNode and adding the nodes names to a string so I path looking similar to this: `#document/html/div/div/ ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the way I fixed my problem was by checking if the `<img>`-tag was inside the `<div class="WordSection1">`. If that wasn't the case I went ahead and checked the `<html>` for every tags position and listing those by using a DFS-Algorithm. Then I went ahead, looked up the nodes positions and compared their indexes:

```
public static DisclaimerPosition GetPositioning(HtmlNode tag, HtmlNode disclaimer, HtmlNode wordSection)
{
    if (tag == null) throw new NullReferenceException("Tag is null");
    if (disclaimer == null) throw new NullReferenceException("Tag is null");
    if (wordSection == null) throw new NullReferenceException("Tag is null");
    if (IsDisclaimerInWordSection1(disclaimer)) return DisclaimerPosition.InWordSection;

    if (tag.Name == "img" || tag.Name == "div" || tag.Attributes.FirstOrDefault(attribute => attribute.Name == "class")?.Value == "WordSection1" || !tag.HasChildNodes)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Tag is invalid, it's value matches disclaimer or wordSection or it has no children");
    }

    var list = GetNodeWithChildren(tag);

    var disclaimerIndex = list.IndexOf(disclaimer);
    var wordSectionIndex = list.IndexOf(wordSection);
    if (disclaimerIndex == -1) throw new ArgumentException("Disclaimer is -1");
    if (wordSectionIndex == -1) throw new ArgumentException("WordSection is -1");

    list.ForEach(node => Console.WriteLine(node.Name + " " + node.Attributes.Where(attribute => attribute.Name == "class").Select(attribute => attribute.Value).FirstOrDefault()));

    return disclaimerIndex < wordSectionIndex ? DisclaimerPosition.AboveWordSection : DisclaimerPosition.UnderneathWordSection;
}

private static List<HtmlNode> GetNodeWithChildren(HtmlNode node)
{
    var nodes = new List<HtmlNode> { node };

    nodes.AddRange(node
            .ChildNodes
            .Where(child => child.NodeType != HtmlNodeType.Text)
            .SelectMany(GetNodeWithChildren)
            .ToList());

    return nodes;

}


public static bool IsDisclaimerInWordSection1(HtmlNode disclaimerTag)
{
    var tag = disclaimerTag;
    while (tag != null)
    {

        if (tag.Name == "div" &&
            tag.HasAttributes &&
            tag.Attributes.Any(tagAttribute => tagAttribute.Name == "class" && tagAttribute.Value == "WordSection1"))
        {
            return true;
        }

        tag = tag.ParentNode;
    }

    return false;
}
```